# MongoDB inserting child document on ID reference

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I migrated my SQL database into a MongoDB database for a project. It migrated the foreign keys as the ID's that were already there. For example I have these two columns linked through the driversId:
[image]

My question is how do I get the driver as a document in the driver_standings collection? Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've used the answer below with $merge to update the collection:

```
db.driverstandings.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "drivers",
    localField: "driverId",
    foreignField: "driverId",
    as: "driver"
  }
}, { $merge: { into:"driverstandings" } }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-lookup) aggregation operator

```js
db.driver_standings.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: "drivers",
    localField: "driverId",
    foreignField: "driverId",
    as: "driver"
  }
}])
```